# EJB 2.1-EJB 3.1 Migration process - Tools, Plugins, and docs

Tags: java, migration, ejb, ejb-3.1, xdoclet

in my company we decided to migrate an EJB 2.1 project to EJB 3.1

Currently we use XDoclet to generate some Interfaces of EJB 2.1 classes.

What I am looking for:

- Any Tip that can help me during this process
- Any Tool or plugin that can assist me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following whitepaper is pretty useful in getting an understanding of the differences

http://www.carthago-ict.nl/xlntcms/user/upload/File/whitepapers/WhitePaper_EJB30.pdf

All the annotations are referenced on the Oracle website

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/ejb30/annotations.html

Sorry I can't recomend any plugins as i've only used EJB 3.0